# How to NOT preserve permission when using scp

Tags: ssh, permissions, scp

I am trying to copy data to one of my servers. Some of the files that are copied have permission 444 on the source machine. This is very annoying, since if the transfer gets interrupted while one of these files is being written, I will be unable to complete writing it, if I don't detel it.

Is there any way to tell `scp` to apply a given set of permissions on the destination side (or just inherit the destination directory's permission?

Preferrably, I would like to make my files 664 and directories 775.

Comment: What is the command you're using now? By default, `scp` doesn't preserve permissions from the source unless you tell it to.

Comment: I know, I looked it up and apparently I'm trying to do what most people are trying to avoid - but over here keeping perms seems to be the default behaviour. The command is, verbatim `scp -r 20160317_* neurohost:incoming
`

Comment: That command should definitely not be preserving permissions. What is the umask on the destination side? Can you confirm that it preserves ownership and permissions after a successful copy? Not that ownership may be preserved simply because you're using the current owner as the destination user account, not because of `scp`.

Comment: How can I determine "the umask on the destination side"? Yes, permissions are preserved after a succesful copy. the names of the users are not the same on the two machines.

Comment: SSH to the destination host and type "umask"

Comment: @John, AFAICT,  scp will copy the permissions, and then unless `-p` is given, apply the umask on top of it. `pax -w files | ssh host 'umask 022; pax -r'` to give 644 for files and 755 for dirs regardless of the permissions on the source.

Comment: @John the umask is `0022`

Answer (score 1):

`scp` copies files and that's it. If you're looking for something more flexible, [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is what you need.

To copy a directory tree, use

```
rsync -a local-directory/ remote.example.com:remote-directory/
```

If the transfer is interrupted, run rsync again, and it'll resume where it left off.

Preserving permissions is probably the right thing, but if you want to apply different arguments, you can use the `--chmod` option. If you really want to ignore local permissions, use `--no-perms`.

If there are large files and your copies get interrupted often, and the remote tree is a new copy that you're filling in with rsync, then use the `--append` option. This way, if a copy gets interrupted in the middle of a file, rsync will finish that file without verifying that the current content of the remote file matches the local content, which can save some time. Once again, do this only if you're sure that a partial remote file *is* the result of an interrupted transfer and not e.g. some older version of the file.